# How to copy or share a linked folder from one project on another in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a linked folder *anyname* in a Eclipse (Mars) project A (is a Dynamic Web Project). I created project B and want to also link *anyname* to it without starting from scratch. Stated other way, how do I copy the linked resource from A to B? Is there a way to configure *anyname* as a "global" shared linked folder and later include in other projects? *anyname* contains a standar in house classes and need to use it in several projects